# Why is the parameter pass on my widget null?

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter. So, I created a class widget code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BoxBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  BoxBuilder({Key key, @required this.text}): super(key: key);
  String text;

  @override
  _BoxBuilderState createState() => _BoxBuilderState();
}

class _BoxBuilderState extends State<BoxBuilder>  {
  _BoxBuilderState({this.text});

  String text;

  double getSize() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120;
    } else {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = getSize() / 2;
    double _height = getSize() / 3;
    return Container(
      width: _width,
      height: _height,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              text==null? 'hello': text,   // LINE 1100
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a list of strings from another class widget declared as

```
List<String> myFoos = [
    'one foo',
    'another foo',
    'more foo',
    'some foo',
    'next foo',
    'all foo'
  ];
```

passed each list as parameter to my class BoxBuilder widget

```
             Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: getSize(),
                  height: getSize(),
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[0]),  //LINE 1001
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[1]),  //LINE 1002
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[2]),  //LINE 1003
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[3]),  //LINE 1004
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[4]),  //LINE 1005
                      BoxBuilder(text:myFoos[5]),  //LINE 1006
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

It seems that the parameters passed are null as I get this result

[image]

If I replace LINE 1100 from BoxBuilder widget class

```
            child: Text(
              text==null? 'hello': text,   // LINE 1100
            ),
```

with just

```
            child: Text(
              text,   // LINE 1100
            ),
```

I get this error

```
   A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
```

called from a LINE 1001, 1002, ... 1006.

I am scratching my head here, it's just passing parameters and why do I get a null value?

Comment: Access to params from state up to component is done through the `widget` instance in your `State<Class>` class. No need for a new constructor in the private State class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a `StatefulWidget` then Try `widget.text` instead.

```dart
child: Text(
  widget.text ?? 'hello',   // LINE 1100
),
```

and also remove this lines as they are not needed

```dart
_BoxBuilderState({this.text});

  String text;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two problems here

1. you re declare variable text, so the new variable value is used which is null
2. since you are using `StatefulWidget` you use it's parameters by `widget.param`

Try this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BoxBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  BoxBuilder({Key key, @required this.text}): super(key: key);
  String text;

  @override
  _BoxBuilderState createState() => _BoxBuilderState();
}

class _BoxBuilderState extends State<BoxBuilder>  {

  double getSize() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120;
    } else {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = getSize() / 2;
    double _height = getSize() / 3;
    return Container(
      width: _width,
      height: _height,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.text ?? 'hello',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: dart provide better way to check null data

```
widget.text ?? 'hello',
```